# LAN to WAN connection between two routers

Tags: wireless-networking

How can i hook up two routers with a LAN to WAN  connection, where #1 router lan is connected to #2 router wan port, and devices of router#1 can access devices of router #2

NOTE:

Don't provide me suggestions for LAN to LAN because doing this is mandatory.

Comment: @DarkNet99 can this be done with static routes?

Comment: You need to give us more details of your mandatory restrictions before anyone can answer this well.

Comment: This should "just work", so long as the two LANs have different address spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I come from, most routers use NAT for the IPv4 network. So say you have a IPP printer on LAN #2, you can access it from LAN #1 by using port forwarding. The problem is you can only do this once. So you could not access a second printer this way without changing the configuration of router #2.

On the other hand if both routers are IPv6 ready, I do not see why all the equipment on both LAN's could not have unique IPv6 addresses. All the equipment should be able to address each other.

I have a similar setup as you describe. Router #1 is **not** IPv6 ready. Router #2 is IPv6 ready and is connected to rest of the IPv6 world via a Hurricane Electric Tunnel. Computers from the outside world have no problem communicating with equipment on LAN #2.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Lan to Lan with DHCP and other services disabled on one is the way to do this, so, it would be good to understand why this doesn't work for you.

That being said, to do the way you want, the simplest solution is to keep services such as DHCP running on both, and have non overlapping IP ranges with an added static route.

So, router 1 - 192.168.0.0/24, with a WAN ip of 10.0.0.1/24, static route pushing 192.168.1.0/24 over default gateway/next hop of 10.0.0.2

router 2 - 192.168.1.0/24 with a WAN ip of 10.0.0.2/24, static route pushing 192.168.0.0/24 over default gateway/next hop of 10.0.0.1

there are hundreds of ways to do this, but, it really depends on the hardware you have available... Also, you will lose outbound internet connection if using residential routers with only one wan socket.

If this isn't what you are looking for, we need a lot more information to help further...

Comment: There are two isps.

Comment: Then this is not what you want at all, all you want to do is buy a dual wan router and be happy...